# How create an Etag with an expire date

Tags: python, http, etag

I'm thinking about create an etag with an expire date.

Actually I create an etag with a large number of parameters but I would like to make it with an expire date.

I have the solution to keep an information in the server side but I prefer to encode any information into.

I'm searching the better way to do that.

```
def etag_max_age(hash_code, max_age=30):
  # do something...
  return etag_with_max_age

def etag_max_age_expired(etag):
  # do some verifications
  return True or False
```

I'm thinking about a solution with cookie

Comment: Could you not just tack the expire date onto the end of the hash.  Something like <hash>-<expiry date>

Comment: O_o ...Of course yes... with a simple unix timestamp. What is the problem with me!

Comment: I guess I will stick that in as the answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to the problem would be to add a timestamp to the end of the etag in the form of `hash-timestamp`.   You could then parse that out when you needed it.